# Getting error when sending application to codename one build server

Tags: codenameone

I have not done any build on the server before, but I have created numerous applications on my system. When trying to send this particular application to the build server, it was giving error on netbeans. This was the error I was getting:

```
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Olubori\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Interview\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\Olubori\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Interview\build
refresh-libs:
Deleting directory C:\Users\Olubori\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Interview\lib\impl
clean:
copy-desktop-override:
Created dir: C:\Users\Olubori\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Interview\build\classes
copy-libs:
deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Olubori\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Interview\build\built-jar.properties
Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller code size and wider device support
Created dir: C:\Users\Olubori\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Interview\build\tmp
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Olubori\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Interview\build\tmp
Created dir: C:\Users\Olubori\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Interview\build\empty
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Olubori\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Interview\build\classes
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
1 warning
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Olubori\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Interview\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: C:\Users\Olubori\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Interview\dist
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Olubori\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Interview\build
C:\Users\Olubori\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Interview\nbproject\build-impl.xml:990: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Olubori\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Interview\nbproject\build-impl.xml:834: copylibs doesn't support the "excludeFromCopy" attribute.

BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

What could be the cause and how will I solve it?

Comment: thank you sir that worked and the application is working now. I am apologizing for accidentally voting it down, wanted to vote it up, i have been looking for ways to undo that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove that attribute from the XML build file, its a NetBeans bug: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codenameone-discussions/X_HMILMsw_Y/jE0xDsL7nfAJ